# Quick check to see if tag exists?

Tags: tags

Just wondered if there's a quick way to see if a specific tag exists from anywhere in the site (by ID)?

I'm creating a navigation bar, and need to include a specific tag... only if it has been created/used.

Cheers, Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you going in the right direction: https://craftcms.com/guides/displaying-tags-that-are-in-use

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @kgrote Updated link.